# US Visa stamp sharing legalities

Tags: visas, usa

So i have a 10 year US B1/B2 visa. Now i am applying for a NZ visa , which asks for, as part of the verification process to share information about other visas one might have with other countries, along with the entry and exit stamps, which should help me obtain a NZ visa. I'm wondering if its legal to share the US Visa stamp info  with the NZ immigration?

Added from comments by OP:
"Providing evidence The evidence you provide helps us confirm that you are a genuine visitor. If you do not provide evidence it may take us longer to process your visa application. Evidence of your travel history Provide a copy of your current and recent passports, including: the photo page, and all pages with visa records, and entry and exit stamps." I figured it shouldn't be a problem, but i was curious though if it would be something that could be termed "against the rules".

To be honest, i figured countries don't like one sharing Visa information with anyone else in case someone else (not all governments have the most secure immigration database) use it to forge a fake visa and try to enter a country because at the departing airport check-in, they casually glance at your visa and let you board the flight. On flight or once one reaches the destination, one can cause havoc. That was my reasoning.

Comment: What makes you believe it would be illegal?

Comment: Many (most?) countries require your passport to process your visa, and they thus can see all visas and stamps in the passport. The same thing happens every time you hand over your passport at a border. So any information on the visa or entry/exit stamps can clearly be shared with other countries. I'm a bit puzzled by the process though. What exactly are they asking for?

Comment: RIght, so if NZ sees that you have legally entered (and left) other countries, then they are more convinced that you will not enter and illegally stay in theirs...

Comment: @meridahu: are you sure? Again, look comment #2: countries are allowed to verify and look at your passport if you want a visa or pass the boundary. Forging passport and visa is common, but immigration officers are trained to check. And do not worry, US has a good database. -- There are cases where you cannot give passport to other countries, but these are exceptions and citizen of such countries known the rules (e.g. Israel passport to some countries).

Comment: I have added two comments to the question and deleted the comments, it is easier for people to find that information now.

Comment: I doubt there are many countries that *don’t* ask applicants for previous visa information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. Nothing about your immigration/visa/travel history is confidential, except in situations where it cannot be disclosed without your permission. It's fine for you to disclose this to NZ (or whomever you like).

Comment: "except to the extent that it cannot be disclosed without your permission" - are you sure about that?

Comment: @Midavalo Well, it's a tautology, so yes. (I think you might be misunderstanding the meaning. A person is able to speak Italian, to the extent that they have learned Italian. That doesn't mean that everyone can speak Italian, or that anyone can speak Italian.)

Comment: @Sneftel but is that true? can't countries disclose your immigration / travel history even without your permission, and might in fact do that routinely?

Comment: @JakeDot in situations where there are no laws preventing them from doing so, of course they can and do.

Comment: But there _are_ privacy laws at most places which will stop them doing this except narrowly carved out exceptions.